# Problema em identificar triângulo em Java

Tags: java

Bom, ainda sou *muito* novo no mundo da programação e estou tentando fazer um simples código onde ele diz se o triângulo é isósceles, escaleno ou equilátero dependendo da medida dos lados digitada. Porém, se eu digitar todas as medidas iguais, ao invés dele apenas dizer que o triângulo é equilátero (todos os lados são iguais), ele tambem diz que é isósceles (apenas dois lados são iguais).

Exemplo:

```
Digite o valor do primeiro lado:
10
Digite o valor do segundo lado:
10
Digite o valor do terceiro lado:
10
O triângulo é equilátero.
O triângulo é isósceles.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Esse é o código:

```
int lado1, lado2, lado3;
    Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite o valor do primeiro lado:");
    lado1 = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor do segundo lado:");
    lado2 = leia.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor do terceiro lado:");
    lado3 = leia.nextInt(); 
    
    if ((lado1 == lado2) && (lado2 == lado3) && (lado3 == lado1)) {
        System.out.println("O triângulo é equilátero.");
    }
    
    if ((lado1 != lado2) && (lado2 != lado3) && (lado3 != lado1)) { //O != significa diferente
        System.out.println("O triângulo é escaleno.");
    }
    
    if ((lado1 == lado2) || (lado2 == lado3) || (lado3 == lado1)) {
        System.out.println("O triângulo é isósceles.");
    }
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer desse jeito:

```
if (x == y && x == z){
    System.out.println("Três lados iguais . Trata-se de um Triangulo Equilatero");
}else if(x == y || x == z || y==z ){
    System.out.println("Dois lados iguais . Trata-se de um Triangulo Isosceles");
    }else
    System.out.println("Três lados diferentes.");
```

mais simples e atinge o objetivo.